# equities industry factor models

Tags: equities, regression, fama-french, paneldata

I am looking for references or practical solutions for the following. In the usual factor approach for equities with panel data regression (for each stock, explain future returns given stock characteristics), how do I add industry specific models?

Example: I have 500 stocks and some stock factors are general like the standard Fama-French factors or momentum (apply to all 500) while others are industry specific eg factors only applicable for Energy stocks. If possible I'd like to allow groups to be overlapping, eg some features are Technology, others Software, etc, but the non-overlapping case is useful too.

One approach is to include all factors. A drawback is the group specific factors will be undefined - would need to define eg average value over group: this doesn't seem very statistically efficient.

A more developed solution would be some Bayesian hierarchical model. However, implementation is more tricky - it may not be worth it compared to a simpler approach where I'd fit a model independently for each group then combine models with a heuristic.

Any reference in the equities literature, or suggestion that is more practical than a full blown Bayesian model?